# Fullcalendar bootstrap popover gets hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I have problems with my bootstrap popovers gets hidden under the rows in full calendar.
I call the function eventRender.

I have tried `container: 'body'`, it doesn't work. Also `trigger: 'focus'` doesn't work either.

As you can see its a function, and it gets called after AJAX: success..if that's what's causing this problem?

My Code:

```js
   function showCalendar(userID){

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today,month',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'prevYear,nextYear'
            },
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            eventRender: function(event, element){
                var dStart = event.start.format("DD MMMM");
                element.popover({
                    animation:true,
                    placement:'top',
                    html:true,
                    title:dStart,
                    trigger: 'click'
                });
            },
            showNonCurrentDates:false,
            weekNumbersWithinDays:true,
            locale: 'sv',
            weekNumbers: true,
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            eventSources: [

                // your event source
                {
                    url: 'DATA/events.json' ,
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {
                        userID: userID
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                    }
                }
            ]
        });

    }
```

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pfsfdekp/3/

Comment: could be z-index? You can examine the elements using your browser's developer tools, to see if any CSS style rules are affecting it, and where those rules are defined.

Comment: i have done that too... z-index is set to 1010.. and i changed it in chrome developer to 100000... no effect.. :/

Comment: can you make a snippet here, or a JSFiddle, which demonstrates the issue, please? It's hard to see what's going on just from the calendar config above - that doesn't really contain any info about the display rules etc.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pfsfdekp/

Comment: Im not sure ive done it right... but basicly this should be it. i dont get enything rendered out here, but i dont know if its the network im currently in that prevents things from being loaded.. ?

Comment: @Wyrm , check this fullcalander: https://github.com/manojkanhasoft/full_calendar.

Comment: @chiragsatapara would you care to share with us why we should be interested in this? Are you just promoting some tool you're involved with, or does it have direct relevance the question? At least give us a reason to look, and not just a random link.

Comment: @ADyson , this is not for promoting a link , he is using a same , like display a popup on mouseover event or task and Wyrm want same like display a popup.He is using a `viewRender` for this , check `assets/demo/demo-calendar.js` where you can find the code for initialize calander.

Comment: @Wyrm wasn't working because you put the JS files in the wrong order, forgot momentJS and had syntax errors. You might have spotted these if you'd looked at the browser console? Also had to put a hard-coded value for userID because it's not defined in your code. Doesn't really matter anyway because the json is clearly not accessible. Fixed version is at https://jsfiddle.net/pfsfdekp/2/ hopefully I can now see the issue if I play about a bit - thanks.

Comment: yes, you are absolutely correct.. didnt think about that, and true, i forgot the moment.js...strangely no errors are loaded in browser console when i run it with ajax requests.?

Comment: now.. here is the error in action https://jsfiddle.net/pfsfdekp/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#popovers states:

> When using popovers on elements within a `.btn-group` or an
>   `.input-group`, or on table-related elements (`<td>`, `<th>`, `<tr>`, `<thead>`,
>   `<tbody>`, `<tfoot>`), you'll have to specify the option `container: 'body'`
>   (documented below) to avoid unwanted side effects (such as the element
>   growing wider and/or losing its rounded corners when the popover is
>   triggered).

In your particular case I think the top of the popovers are being hidden because they are appended to the DOM within the `<td>` of the calendar cell, but are too big for it, so because of the absolute positioning used, any part of the popover which falls outside the dimensions of the `<td>` gets clipped. I'm not absolutely 100% sure this is the correct technical reason, but from observation that's what appears to be happening (e.g, if you change the popover's "top" value from -30px to -10px, you can see more of it, but the top bit outside the calendar day cell is still missing).

Anyway, to fix it simply add that option to the popover configuration:

```
element.popover({
    animation: true,
    placement: 'top',
    html: true,
    title: dStart,
    trigger: 'click',
    container: 'body' //extra option
});
```

This causes the popovers to be appended to the main `<body>` tag of the DOM, where they are not constrained by a table cell. Since they are positioned absolutely, they still appear in the right place in relation to the event they are associated with. You may append it to any DOM element you wish, but `body` is simplest in this case.

https://jsfiddle.net/pfsfdekp/4/ demonstrates a working version.

P.S. You mentioned in the question that you'd tried this already, but from what I can observe in the JSFiddle, there's no reason it shouldn't be possible.

Comment: I do thank you, and i copied your code into my project, but the error still reamins..its very confusing since it works in your JSFiddle? Why isnt my solution appending to body? Is there som other way to load in popovers, some other method rather than eventRender?

Comment: "Why isnt my solution appending to body?" Have you verified that this is definitely the case? You can right-click the popover and inspect it's position in the DOM to see what it's appended to. If it doesn't append to body, where does it append? I can't see how it could go against the instruction in the options, unless there's some other error happening, or some conflicting CSS or JS code, or an ancient version of jquery or bootstrap or something.

Comment: with risk of sounding as a noob, exactly where do i find information about the popovers position in DOM?, and what it appends to?

Comment: Like I said, "You can right-click the popover". Right-click the popover when it appears on your screen, and choose the "Inspect" option from the menu. It'll open up the browser's developer tools and take you to a view of the current state of the page's HTML, focused on the "inspected" element in the markup. Then you can clearly see where in the page structure it is sitting. Chrome has probably the best tools for this, followed by Firefox. IE's tools are bit naff in comparison, IMHO.

Comment: Aha.. ive used that to check CSS and HTML structure of certain objects... now, when i do as you described.. the popover appears to be under the <tr> tag.. not body. Well that explains why its clipped. but ive added the container option, and its not helping.. could it possibly be distorted since im loading the fullalendar via ajax?

Comment: I guess it could be, although it's hard to say why that would be exactly, the DOM is still basically the same, you just load part of it later. Simple experiment - are you able to temporarily change your page so the calendar is created when the page loads, but within the same HTML structure? And see if that is indeed the issue or not

Comment: exactly my thought, i load the page and the DOM, and after that is loaded (on success function in my ajax call) i load the calendar..som my question is, is there a workaround for this? LiveQuery?

Comment: did you carry out my experiment, to see if it really is the later loading of the calendar which causes this?

Comment: Yes, i did, and it is as you say, the later loading of the calendar makes the popover not appendingt to body. Im not sure on how to proceed, is there any other way to load the calendar so it loads correctly in the DOM?

Comment: well, it is required that the calendar is not loaded until after this ajax call completes? Could you load it, but hide it, and then just make it visible when the ajax completes?